# .NET - Socket Send Not Blocking

Tags: .net, sockets, synchronous

For weeks I thought that my algorithm that loops through the files and sends it to the server have bugs on it. Then I started to wonder if the connection itself is the problem.

I am using sockets synchronously to send byte() to the server. 
I made a logger to see if the socket is blocking the thread before continuing instructions.

This is what I got:

```
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.779 AM] Sending
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.780 AM] Sending done
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.820 AM] Sending
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.821 AM] Sending done
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.878 AM] Sending
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.878 AM] Sending done
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.938 AM] Sending
[08/18/2015 02:25:58.939 AM] Sending done
```

As you can see, between "sending" and "sending done" is 1 milisecond.

I am using this code to send.

```
Public Sub SendSync(ByVal bytData_ As Byte())
    Try
        TestLogger.Log("Sending")
        If Not blnConnected Then TestLogger.Log("Not connected") : Return
        objSocket.Send(bytData_, SocketFlags.None)
        TestLogger.Log("Sending done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        TestLogger.Log("Send Error")
        Disconnect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I also enabled :

```
objSocket.Blocking = True
```

My question is that, Am I doing something wrong here?
And is there other way to tell if the socket is sending or receiving?
Thank you.

Comment: The operating system provides a nice big buffer for TCP stream data, the Send() call simply copies your Byte() into that buffer.  There's a long pause between Send() calls so pretty low odds you provide data faster than it can be transmitted and actually end up getting blocked.

Answer (score 1):

This example from msdn will give you a response from the remote device.

```
'Receive the response from the remote device.
Dim bytesRec As Integer = sender.Receive(bytes)
Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}", _
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec))
```

Here is a link to the full example.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hello, I already have a fully functioning class.
It's in a loop so I cannot shutdown it everytime I send something.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the code for clarity. Can you use the .receive to determine if you are getting a respone from your send.

Comment: I see, thank you. I did that already, but in remote cases the ping between PCs are affects the performance. It should be only one sided sending and one sided receiving.